# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with SwipeView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am trying to use a ViewPager to display articles. 
First I have a ListView with articles titles and when you click on one of them you land in a ViewPager where you can see previous or following article by swiping.

However I can't get rid of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... And the stacktrace is not very helpfull.

Here is my Homepage (where you find the ListView with the clickable articles titles)

```
public class HomepageActivity extends MenuActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

    actionBarTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    actionBarMenuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    actionBarAccountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ParallaxListView listView = (ParallaxListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    HomepageItemAdapter adapter = new HomepageItemAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    RelativeLayout homepageParallaxHeader = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_parallax, null);
    listView.addParallaxedHeaderView(homepageParallaxHeader);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    final List<ExternalContent> articles = db.getAllArticles();
    adapter.updateData(articles);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomepageActivity.this, ExternalContentPagerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("external_content_id", id);
            intent.putExtra("external_contents", (Serializable) articles);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the ViewPager Activity

```
public class ExternalContentPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
// When requested, this adapter returns a DemoObjectFragment,
// representing an object in the collection.
ExternalContentPagerAdapter externalContentPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.external_content_view_pager);

    // ViewPager and its adapters use support library
    // fragments, so use getSupportFragmentManager.
    List<ExternalContent> externalContents = (List<ExternalContent>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("external_contents");
    Long externalContentId = getIntent().getLongExtra("external_content_id", 0);

    externalContentPagerAdapter = new ExternalContentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), externalContents, externalContentId);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(externalContentPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(externalContentId.intValue());
}
}
```

The adapter :

```
public class ExternalContentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<ExternalContent> externalContents;
private final Long externalContentId;

public ExternalContentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, List<ExternalContent> externalContents, Long externalContentId) {
    super(supportFragmentManager);
    this.externalContents = externalContents;
    this.externalContentId = externalContentId;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new ExternalContentPagerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Our object is just an integer :-P
    args.putSerializable(ExternalContentPagerFragment.EXTERNAL_CONTENT, externalContents.get(i));
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return externalContents != null ? externalContents.size() : 0;
}
}
```

The page fragment :

```
public class ExternalContentPagerFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String EXTERNAL_CONTENT = "external_content";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.external_content, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    ExternalContent externalContent = (ExternalContent) args.getSerializable(EXTERNAL_CONTENT);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView content = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(externalContent.pictureUrl).into(image);
    title.setText(externalContent.title);
    content.setText(Html.fromHtml(externalContent.content));

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Here is the not helping stacktrace...

```
12-02 16:08:26.200    3059-3059/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2036; index=2036
        at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:170)
        at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:140)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:80)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:59)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5901)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5741)
        at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6098)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I used debugger stop points in theses classes but I didnt find anything...
Thank you!

Comment: this `Html.fromHtml(externalContent.content)` could be the issue, as it seems android is lost somewhere with regard to styling. I would recommend you search for the `2036` characters text you are using, and double check it.

Comment: I removed the fromHtml method and displayed plain text and it worked! Is there a way I could display HTML properly? the 2036 was a random letter...

Comment: it could be an unclosed html tag. you will need to identify precisely which html content causes the issue, then analyze it to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot! 
Feel free to answer if you want the stackoverflow points! :)

Comment: I feel a complete answer should include the exact reason for the issue, which I am not able to provide, since I have not verified what I suggested about the malformed HTML.